# minishift ansible broker configuration issue

Tags: openshift, minishift

I followed the instruction to install ansible broker into minishfit. I made the following:

```
minishift version
minishift v1.15.1+f19ac09
CDK v3.4.0-2

oc cluster up --service-catalog=true
oc login -u system:admin
oc new-project ansible-service-broker
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift/ansible-service-broker/master/templates/simple-broker-template.yaml | oc process -n "ansible-service-broker" -f - | oc create -f -

oc get clusterserviceclasses --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,DISPLAYNAME:spec.externalMetadata.displayName | grep APB
0e991006d21029e47abe71acc255e807 Pyzip Demo (APB)
135bd0df0401e2fdd52fd136935014fb NGINX (APB)
1dda1477cace09730bd8ed7a6505607e PostgreSQL (APB)
5d0062cce443e5ecb8438ca5f664dcd7 Kibana (APB)
67042296c7c95e84142f21f58da2ebfe MariaDB (APB)
693cb128e68365830c913631300deac0 Pyzip Demo Database (APB)
6df7afbd132c094704b4a8bfd44378c0 ManageIQ (APB)
880ef3b4ba5fa8d80908e9974228e603 AWX (APB)
9f7da06f179b895a8ee5f9a3ce4af7ef Hello World (APB)
a946a139a9308a59bf642ac52b4ba317 Wordpress-HA (APB)
ab24ffd54da0aefdea5277e0edce8425 Hastebin (APB)
aff6d7bb9c7f57c9ce8b742228e4caa3 Elasticsearch (APB)
b43a4272a6efcaaa3e0b9616324f1099 Hello World Database (APB)
ba9c2d4db404ce97111bea80225de968 RocketChat (APB)
c65fbd4e701cb71d74fd2cc35e14432b Amazon RDS - PostgreSQL (APB)
ca91b61da8476984f18fc13883ae2fdb Etherpad (APB)
ddd528762894b277001df310a126d5ad MySQL (APB)
eebf92c7670f30007a4b8db3a8166d5c The Lounge (APB)
f4509733ca0636df3d69b6af53260160 Jenkins (APB)
f6c4486b7fb0cdac4b58e193607f7011 Mediawiki (APB)
f755257efed3e3d43c8b82afd0db1181 Prometheus (APB)
```

When I tried to run apb list this error occur:
apb list
Contacting the ansible-service-broker at: https://asb-1338-ansible-service-broker.127.0.0.1.nip.io/openshift-automation-service-broker/v2/catalog
ERROR: Failed broker request (get) https://asb-1338-ansible-service-broker.127.0.0.1.nip.io/openshift-automation-service-broker/v2/catalog
Exception occurred! local variable 'InsecureRequestWarning' referenced before assignment

oc whoami
system:admin

oc login -u system:admin
Logged into "https://127.0.0.1:8443" as "system:admin" using existing credentials.

You have access to the following projects and can switch between them with 'oc project ':

ansible-service-broker
custom-broker
default
kube-public
kube-service-catalog
kube-system
myproject
openshift
openshift-infra
openshift-node
openshift-template-service-broker
openshift-web-console
apb list
Contacting the ansible-service-broker at: https://asb-1338-ansible-service-broker.127.0.0.1.nip.io/openshift-automation-service-broker/v2/catalog
ERROR: Failed broker request (get) https://asb-1338-ansible-service-broker.127.0.0.1.nip.io/openshift-automation-service-broker/v2/catalog
Exception occurred! local variable 'InsecureRequestWarning' referenced before assignment